# Location of configuration files in apache 2.4.6

Tags: apache

I built and install the latest version of apache, 2.4.6 on ubuntu 12.04.
I specified the prefix (installation location) as

```
/home/[user-name]/apache
```

After it was done, i was able to start apache by running

```
./home/[user-name]/apache/bin/apachectl
```

In previous version that i installed from repos, the configuration files such as
sites-available, sites_enabled etc were located in

```
/etc/apache
```

Where can i find the conf files for this version.
Or is there more i need to do after compiling and installing?

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing under the prefix, but I'm not sure. For instance, `/home/[user-name]/apache/etc`.

Comment: I didn't find it there, looks like only the main installation files are found under the prefix

Comment: Ahh, well I don't think those config files you mentioned are part of the standard distribution, they are probably added by whoever built the packages you had previously installed.

Answer (score 0):

By default the location for httpd.conf should be

> /home/[user-name]/apache/conf/httpd.conf